# Dropbox long polling for changes to one file (Javascript API)

Tags: javascript, file, dropbox, long-polling

My application is only interested in changes that happen to one file in Dropbox. What is the easiest/most efficient way to watch for changes in that one file?

I know there is a [long polling method](http://coffeedoc.info/github/dropbox/dropbox-js/master/classes/Dropbox/Client.html#pollForChanges-instance), but that looks like will fire events for any changes that the app has access to. My application requires access to the entire Dropbox account as the target file is chosen by the end user from anywhere in their account. Webhooks are also not an option as this is for a Chrome extension.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know if `dropbox.js` supports this option yet, but the [`/delta`](https://www.dropbox.com/developers/core/docs#delta) endpoint supports a `path_prefix` option that would let you specify the exact path you want to follow. [`/longpoll_delta`](https://www.dropbox.com/developers/core/docs#longpoll-delta) takes a delta cursor, so as long as you applied a path prefix when you created the cursor, your longpoll call will only return when something at that path changes.

Comment: Looks like they don't yet support this option, but if you have any "pull" with the JS team (ha ha) I just created a pull request that adds it. https://github.com/dropbox/dropbox-js/pull/197

Comment: It looks Dropbox would prefer if /delta is not called more often than once every 5 minutes. If longpoll-delta reports changes before that time is up, should I still wait before calling it again? Or is it considered OK in this case because I know that changes have occurred?

Comment: As far as I'm concerned, it's okay to call as soon as longpoll_delta returns. (That's what our Sync SDKs do.)